# Sending Simple Data to Other Apps using React Native in Android

Tags: android, react-native

I have two react native apps say App 1 and App 2.Now i need to start App 2 from App 1 passing simple text data.On research using [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tqcLQ.png) link from android documents i am able to call the activity of App 2 from App 1 using indents,

[image: Sample Image of opening App2 from App1]

But the question is will i be able to pass these data to the React Native screen of App 2.My App 2 has a dummy Activity class to receive indents from other apps but if there is a much neat approach without using Indents to pass data between apps in React Native is most welcome.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass your simple text from App1 to App2 via intents (Android )

for this , In  **App1**

install this plugin

```
npm i react-native-send-intent
```

Then send your data as following ways

> Option 1 : as implicit intent

```
 var SendIntentAndroid = require('react-native-send-intent');

SendIntentAndroid.sendText({
  title: 'Please share this text',
  text: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per error erant eu, antiopam intellegebat ne sed',
  type: SendIntentAndroid.TEXT_PLAIN
});
```

> Option 2 : Specify Your App

```
 // You can  specify arbitrary intent extras to be passed to the app
    SendIntentAndroid.openApp('com.App2', 
         {"App2PropData1": "just because", "App2PropData2": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, per error erant eu, antiopam intellegebat ne sed"}).then((wasOpened) => {});
```

**In App2**

this data will be available in the `props`

```
    export default class App extends Component {

    render() {
        console.log('App props', this.props);
        console.log('App2PropData1', this.props.App2PropData1);
        console.log('App2PropData2', this.props.App2PropData2);
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to receive data through props earlier.
But I solved it by adding following code in Mainactivity.java in second app

```
@Override
    protected ReactActivityDelegate createReactActivityDelegate() {
        return new ReactActivityDelegate(this, getMainComponentName()) {
            @Override
            protected Bundle getLaunchOptions() {
                Intent intent = MainActivity.this.getIntent();
                return intent.getExtras();
            }
        };
    }
```

and get data via props like

```
console.log(props.name)
```

where you want to receive data in second app.
Hope this will help.

Comment: I have another query that I am able to send data from App1 to App2 in react native by using react-native-send-intent when App2 is only installed(App2 is not in the background state). But when App2 opens first and keeps it in the background state after that, when I opened App1 and send data to App2 it is not reflecting in App2. Can anyone suggest how to solve this project with example?